# css - centering a text under a text

Tags: css, center

I have a text that I want in a specific color that says something about a text below it. I want that text to be centered so I use

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

But it doesnt position in the center and instead it gets positioned in the left of the screen. Simply put, whats the easiest and most effiecent way to center an element. ANY element.

Answer (score 0):

text

```
text-align: center;
```

tags

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

other tags

```
left: 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to center text is

```
text-align: center;
```

If you use the `margin: 0 auto;` technique the element needs to be a [block-level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) or given `display: block;` and you need to give it a `width` (in px or %).

Answer (score 0):

All methods are correct.
Keep in mind that `text align` do not have effect on inline level elements.
`margin: auto` is not a hack , it is perfectly relevant and correct according to the specification.For learning more about margin: auto see this link http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins

Answer (score 0):

There are various techniques for centering elements. Usability of those techniques depends on other properties, inherited or you applied via css. For example, for centering an inline or inline-block level element, you may use `text-align:center;` to the parent. But for centering a block level element, you have to use a specific `width` along with `margin:0 auto;`. Certainly there have other techniques too.